# Implement Global Search in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to implement search like in shopping carts.
I have more than one table. I use model function given below

```
function xenSelectCarsGlobal($key=null) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('sel_car_details');
        $this->db->join('derivative', 'derivative.der_id = sel_car_details.der_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('variant', 'variant.var_id = sel_car_details.var_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('model', 'model.model_id = sel_car_details.mod_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('make', 'make.make_id = sel_car_details.mk_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('car_color', 'car_color.color_id = sel_car_details.color_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('body_type', 'body_type.body_id = sel_car_details.body_type_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('fuel_type', 'fuel_type.fuel_id = sel_car_details.fuel_type_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('gallery', 'gallery.sel_carid = sel_car_details.sel_car_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('sel_car_details.status', '5');
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('fuel_type.fuel_name', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('sel_car_details.engine_size', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('sel_car_details.mileage', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('derivative.der_name', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('variant.variant', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('model.model', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('make.maker', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('car_color.col_name', $key);
        if(!empty($key))
            $this->db->or_like('body_type.body_name', $key);

        $qry = $this->db->get();

        if ($qry->num_rows() != 0) {
            return $qry->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }return 1;
    }
```

It's working properly.But the problem is 
suppose body name is xxx, color yellow then i search for xxx it show the result and i search for xxx it show the result. But i type xxx yellow in search box it show nothing. I want to list both the result.
Please give me a solution...

Comment: `$this->db->where('sel_car_details.status', '5');` is useless here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your query. Try this:

```
function xenSelectCarsGlobal($strQuery=null) 
    {
        $arrKeywords = ($strQuery !== null) ? explode(' ', $strQuery) : array();

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('sel_car_details');
        $this->db->join('derivative', 'derivative.der_id = sel_car_details.der_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('variant', 'variant.var_id = sel_car_details.var_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('model', 'model.model_id = sel_car_details.mod_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('make', 'make.make_id = sel_car_details.mk_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('car_color', 'car_color.color_id = sel_car_details.color_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('body_type', 'body_type.body_id = sel_car_details.body_type_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('fuel_type', 'fuel_type.fuel_id = sel_car_details.fuel_type_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('gallery', 'gallery.sel_carid = sel_car_details.sel_car_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('sel_car_details.status', '5');
        if(!empty($arrKeywords)) {
            foreach($arrKeywords as $strKeyword) {
                $this->db->or_like('fuel_type.fuel_name', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('sel_car_details.engine_size', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('sel_car_details.mileage', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('derivative.der_name', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('variant.variant', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('model.model', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('make.maker', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('car_color.col_name', $strKeyword);
                $this->db->or_like('body_type.body_name', $strKeyword);
            }
        }

        $qry = $this->db->get();

        if ($qry->num_rows() != 0) {
            return $qry->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution will also get those result which `sel_car_details.status` is not 5.

Comment: I don't know this DB-framework but the problem seems to be the condition connection by *or*. This way the SQL-statement is like
`SELECT .... WHERE sel_car_details.status LIKE 5 OR fuel_type.fuel_name LIKE 'keyword' OR ... `

You need something like
`SELECT .... WHERE sel_car_details.status LIKE 5 AND (fuel_type.fuel_name LIKE 'keyword' OR sel_car_details.engine_size LIKE 'keyword' OR ...)`

Comment: Have a look at [CodeIgniter::Method-chaining](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#method-chaining)